# Showing 95% CI for predicted independent variable based on user inpu DVs in shiny app

Tags: r, regression, shiny

I have a regression model developed from grades; I'd like users to input their grades and get the 95% CI for their predicted test score. My output code gives the following error:

```
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
Warning: Error in eval: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
```

Stack trace (innermost first):

```
73: eval
72: model.frame.default
71: model.frame
70: predict.lm
69: renderTable [C:\Users\Mark\Documents\R\COMLEXPrediction/server.R#25]
68: func
67: output$values
 1: shiny::runApp
```

Here is the UI code:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Predict Your COMLEX Level 1 Score"),
  sidebarPanel(
    # Simple integer interval
      sliderInput("integer", "Input your Psychiatry 1522 Grade:", 
                min=0, max=100, value=85),

    # Simple integer interval
    sliderInput("integer2", "Input your Pharmacology 1611 Grade:", 
                min=0, max=100, value=85),

    # Decimal interval with step value
    sliderInput("decimal", "Input your Year 1 GPA:", 
            min = 0.00, max = 4.00, value = 3.0, step= 0.01)
    ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("values"))
))
```

And the server code:

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv('2015_CourseGradesandCOMLEXL1Disciplines_NoNames.csv')
comlex.lm <- lm(COMLEXL1_Total ~ PSYC1522_Total + Year1_GPA +         PHAR1633_Total, data=data, na.action = "na.exclude")

# Define server logic for slider examples
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of
  # the values
  predictdata <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("PSYC1522", 
               "PHAR1611",
               "GPA"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$integer, 
                             input$integer2,
                             input$decimal)), 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  }) 

    # Show the values using an HTML table
  output$values <- renderTable({
   comlex.pred <- predict.lm(comlex.lm, data.frame)
      output$regTab <- renderTable({
      if(!is.null(input$independent)){
       summary(runRegression())$coefficients
      } else {
        print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
      }
    })
  })
})
```

I've tried tracing my closures, and changing the call from values to table, with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are asking for `predict.lm(comlex.lm, data.frame)`; `data.frame` isn't a variable you've created, it's a base-R function.  I think you mean `predict.lm(comlex.lm, predictdata)` ... ?

Comment: You should also make clear what sort of 95% confidence interval you want. Is it for an estimated mean value or a prediction interval? I think "predicted independent variable based on user inpu DVs " strongly suggests you ant prediction intervals, so should be using `type="prediction"`.